# EmberJS access properties without model object

Tags: ember.js

I've got my route setup like so

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('organization', params.organization_id);
  }
});
```

When I'm printing out the properties, I have to do this in my template.

```
{{ model.name }}
```

Is there anyway I can drop the model part so it's just name?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The standard design pattern is to leave it in: http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/

Comment: @WebDevDude, If you try to access the properties without the `model` then it will check whether such property exists in the controller. If so, it will be rendered. It will not check inside `model`. Please do update the reason why you don't want the `model`. So that, the community can help you better. Thanks

Comment: @phkavitha I didn't know it was a bad practice. I actually thought I was doing something wrong because {{ model.name }} just didn't look right to me.

Comment: @WebDevDude it's actually what ObjectControllers (now deprecated) used to do, they'd proxy your model to the controller so you could access it in the template as only the property name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it if you want, though it's not great practice. In the setupController hook,

```
setupController(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model);
  controller.set('name', model.get('name'));
}
```

It'll set a property on the controller so you can access it in the template as `{{name}}`